# Why this ImageView is not showing my image?

Tags: android, imageview

I have this `imageview` on my layout:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/profileImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/profileImageLabel"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:maxWidth="90px"
    android:maxHeight="90px"/>
```

And i am giving it the source of the image dynamically on the onCreate():

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("c:/logo.png");

        profileImage.setImageBitmap(bm);
        profileImage.invalidate();
```

But when i test my app, it doesn't shows the image, it only shows black screen.

Why is the `imageview` not displaying and only a black screen instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it seams to me that your filepath is wrong. You are testing this in the emulator right? The emulator cannot access your harddrive or anything else that is not a part of the emulator.
What you should do is add your image to your drawable folder in eclipse (if thats what you are using) and then load the file by writing:

```
Resources r = this.getResources();
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(r, R.drawable.logo);
```

Comment: and what happens if i need to get the file from the mobile? (i need this to my app, because the users will can select a imagen from their mobile and use as profile image)

Comment: Well then you can do the way you have done, just enter the correct filepath. You can read more about that here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

Answer (score 0):

You can use a block like this

```
File iconFile = new File("/path/to/image.png");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(iconFile);
Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
fis.close();
```

to get the bitmap for a file that you have "on disk". `/path/to/image.png` is the path where the image is stored.